# Post to API before saving to database in django class-based views

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a class-based view like this:

```
class UpdateProfileView(UpdateView):
    model = models.Profile
    form_class = forms.ProfileForm
    template_name = 'userprofile/add_user_profile.html'
    success_url = '/'
```

And I want to add a way that before it updates the data to the database it also updates the data to a custom API, but I don't know much about django's class-based views.

How do I hook it up that before sending the data to the database I get the form data and post it into the API I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like overriding [`form_valid()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#basic-forms) would be a good way to go.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    post_to_api(form.cleaned_data)
    # now call superclass to save the form
    return super(UpdateProfileView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: I think `save()` is better suited because posting to an API is also a save functionality.